# Woocommerce - How to remove price and add category to up-sells and related?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

In my single-product, I have a related and up-sells section with 4 products each.

The thing is, I don't want the price and buy button to show up. I could hide them with css but I believe there's a better way, with hooks.

So it should be only the image, product title and category, how can I add the category as well?
Can someone help me out?

By the way, here's the [link](http://olsnegocios.com.br/clientes/cristinarezendeart/wp/produto/ocean-serie-sob-encomenda/) to the single-product just in case.

Comment: If the user manipulating things on the screen isn't really a concern, then using css/js to toggle it is a good solution. Don't overcomplicate it if you don't need to.

Comment: But how will I add the category to it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I figured it out.
For the price and button, I just hid it with css (display: none).
And to add the category:

In `functions.php`:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title', 'add_product_cat');
function add_product_cat() {
    global $product;
    $product_cats = wp_get_post_terms($product->id, 'product_cat');
    $count = count($product_cats);
    foreach($product_cats as $key => $cat){
        echo '<span class="category-title" onclick="return false;">'.$cat->name.'</span>';
        if($key < ($count-1)){
            echo ' ';
        }
        else{
            echo ' ';
        }
    }
}
```